# Ambiguous call (conversion from char* to lambda vs std::string)

Tags: c++, c++11

According to my compiler gcc-4.6 the call to func in the example below is ambigous.

```
void func(const std::string &str) {
}

void func(std::function<std::string()> f) {
}

void test() {
    func("Hello");
}
```

Is the compiler correct in saying this? If I remove the first overload this code won't compile as it will fail to instantiate the templates involved.

Is there anyway to resolve this beside either renaming one of the two functions or by explicitly converting to std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also add a third overload to explicitly capture the string literal case:

```
void func(char const* cstr) {
    return func(std::string(cstr));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be resolved by SFINAE in the constructor of `std::function`. However, it doesn't seem to be required and isn't provided by GCC. So you can't portably depend on it working out.

Comment: I'm not even sure whether implementations are allowed to do this. I would be glad if someone could find a spec reference or explain further.

Comment: @Johannes The library requirements specify that the passed argument to the templated constructors of `std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>` 'shall be Callable (20.8.11.2) for argument types ArgTypes and return type R.' (n3290, 20.8.11.2.1/7). So it would make sense from a quality of implementation point of view to assert on that. SFINAE is a possibility but I'm not sure I'd like that.

Comment: @Luc, does it mean that behavior is undefined if the type is not callable? if not, it ca be detected by SFINAE with usercode whether the ctor is viable or not, hence it would fall not within as-if